# partitioning a set into denumerable subsets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $A$ and $B$ be sets. If there exists an injection $f : A\to B,$ then write $|A|\leq |B|,$ where $|A|$ is the size of the set $A$. Let $A$ be a nonempty set. Show that $|\mathbb{N}|\leq |A|$ iff $A$ can be partitioned into denumerable sets. That is, there is a set of sets $\{K_i\}_{i\in I} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A)$ so that

> - Each $K_i$ is denumerable
> - $K_i\cap K_j=\emptyset$ for $i\neq j$
> - $A = \cup_{i\in I} K_i$

Suppose $A$ can be partitioned into denumerable sets. Then $A = \cup_{i\in I} K_i$ for some index set $I$, where the $K_i$'s are disjoint and denumerable. In particular, one can find a bijection $f : \mathbb{N}\to K_{\alpha}, \alpha \in I.$ This is clearly an injection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $A$ (as $K_\alpha \subseteq A$), so $|\mathbb{N}|\leq |A|.$

Suppose there is an injection $f : \mathbb{N}\to A.$ Then $A$ is clearly infinite, since its size is at least the size of an infinite set. Also, $A$ has a denumerable subset. I'm not really sure how to show that the given family exists, though I think Zorn's lemma should be useful. However, I'm not really sure which family of sets to consider. For instance, would it be useful to consider the set of all denumerable subsets of $A$? And if so, how would I define the partial order?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Let $\mathscr{P}$ be the family of all pairwise disjoint families of countably infinite subsets of $A$, partially ordered by inclusion. Use Zorn’s lemma to show that $\mathscr{P}$ has a maximal element $\mathscr{M}$. If $\bigcup\mathscr{M}=A$, we’re done. If not, let $F=A\setminus\bigcup\mathscr{M}$.

- Show that $F$ is finite.
- Then fix some $M\in\mathscr{M}$, let $M'=M\cup F$, and show that $(\mathscr{M}\setminus\{M\})\cup\{M'\}$ is a partition of $A$ into countably infinite subsets.